# harmonic conjugate question

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $a$, $b$ be harmonic conjugates on a region $S$. Suppose $a(x,y) = c_{1}$ and $b(x,y) = c_{2}$ where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are constants. Show these curves intersect orthogonally.

I was given a hint which says that if $(x(t),y(t))$ is the curve (parametrized), then establish that $(a_{x}, a_{y}) \cdot (x'(t), y'(t)) = 0$.

Attempt: By the chain rule, $a(x,y) = c_{1} \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-a_{x}}{a_{y}}$, and $b(x,y) = c_{2} \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-b_{x}}{b_{y}} = \frac{a_{y}}{a_{x}}$ by the Cauchy Riemann Equations. This is where I am stuck at. How do I use the hint from here?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first we prove the hint: if $(x,y):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is such that
$$a(x(t),y(t))=c_1$$
then, taking the derivative in $t$, we have
$$a_x(x(t), y(t))\dot{x}(t) + a_y(x(t), y(t))\dot{y}(t)=0$$
so the vectors $(\dot{x}(t), \dot{y}(t))$ and $(a_x(x(t), y(t)), a_y(x(t), y(t)))$ are perpendicular for every $t$.

Now, let $(x_1, y_1)$ be the curve $a(x,y)=c_1$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ be the curve $b(x,y)=c_2$.

You correctly observed that
$$a_xb_x=-b_ya_y$$
by the Cauchy-Riemann equation. Therefore
$$(a_x, a_y)\cdot(b_x, b_y)=a_xb_x+a_yb_y=0\;.$$
This means that $(a_x, a_y)\perp(b_x, b_y)$, but we proved, with the hint, that
$$(\dot{x}_1, \dot{y}_1)\perp(a_x, a_y)\qquad (\dot{x}_2, \dot{y}_2)\perp(b_x, b_y)\;.$$
As we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if $v\perp w$ and $u\perp w$ then $v\parallel u$, so we conclude that
$$(\dot{x}_1, \dot{y}_1)\perp(\dot{x}_2,\dot{y}_2)\;.$$
I.e., the two curves are perpendicular when they meet.